# Does this theorem hold for the infinite case as well?

Tags: group-theory

Consider the theorem:

> Orbits of a normal subgroup are equal in size when the full group acts transitively

This is stated and proved [here](http://planetmath.org/OrbitsOfANormalSubgroupAreEqualInSizeWhenTheFullGroupActsTransitively.html). I wonder: Does this theorem also hold infinite sets on which the group acts ? If not, can someone give a counterexample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $O_1, O_2$ are two orbits of $H$, then there exists $g\in G$ such that $x\mapsto gx$ is a bijection $O_1\to O_2$. (The existence follows from $G$ acting transitively, bijectivity by specifying the inverse $x\mapsto g^{-1}x$)